# Formula for coordinates in a linearly increasing interval

Tags: list, indexing, formula, intervals

If I have a list of pairs of separated values, how can I calculate which index a given number falls into (that is, the input is in the interval)? For example:

```
f( [[0, 2], [3, 6], [7, 10]], 4 ) == 1
```

Edit - To clarify, I know the naive algorithm is quite obvious. I feel like there's a constant time (or at least better than linear) solution.

Comment: Are all the intervals non-overlapping and monotonic?

Comment: They might overlap at the boundaries (i.e., [0, 2], [2, 5]), and yes I think it's monotonic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in Python

```
def f(intervals, value):
    for i in intervals:
        if (value >= i[0]) and (value <= i[0]):
            return True
    return False
```